# Query a Datatable/DataSet with SQL statement

Tags: sql, datatable, dataset, sqlcommand

Is there a way to query a dataset or datatable with a SQL statement in the same way as I do it with a real database in C#?

For example, I have a datatable `X` (in memory) and I want to run a select command on that datatable:

```
Select * from X
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you want to display the data which are in datatable or insert the data into sql

Comment: I want to be able to do both. But it is important that I can use the exact same statements that I use for the database.

Comment: much like DataTable's [Select method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you want.. Also, take a look at LINQ technique, its quite neighbouring to your question.

Comment: To execute the same queries, you will have to call SQL statements. Which is quite not handy when you operate in c# environment for many reasons.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is handy or not for now. How do I do that? I tried but didn't work so far. How do I call sql statements on a dataset or datatable? There is always a sqlconnection required?

Comment: Yes you will always require connection with your sql. & it is not very difficult to insert or update your datatble or dataset with sql

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do like this.

Suppose dt is your datatable then you will need to apply for loop for getting eac and every record from the Datatable or Dataset.

```
for (int i = 0; dt.Rows.Count > i; i++)
            {
                //Your Query
            }
```

insert query like

```
insert into tableName values ( dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString(),
dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString(), 
dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString() etc...)
```

If you want to avoid looping you can also try this
[SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx)

[SqlBulkCopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)

Comment: thanks but thats not what I'm looking for. I want to do an sqlcommand on a dataset in the exact same way I will do it on a real datatable. Or at least I want to know if this is not possible at all

Comment: If you want to avoid looping then you can use sql bulk class.